# Python stream WebSocket messages

Tags: python, web-scraping, websocket

I got this [site](https://www.mozzartbet.co.ke/en#/live/sport/1) am trying to get live updates from   the websocket. Below is my code

```
import websocket


def on_message(ws, message):
    print(message)

def on_close(ws, close_status_code,close_msg):
    print("closed connection")


socket = "wss://www.mozzartbet.co.ke/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket"

ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(socket,on_message= on_message, on_close=on_close)

ws.run_forever()
```

Instead of getting the livestream of the data the code prints true, where could I be wrong

Comment: Your code is valid (it works with `wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/btcusdt@trade` for instance). However, mozzartbet is behind a cloudflare proxy, and this might be the reason you cannot get the data. In future you can use `websocket.enableTrace(True)` for debugging.

Comment: @platipus_on_fire_333 how can you pass the headers and cookies to the websocket to avoid being blocked by cloudflare

Comment: https://websocket-client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html?highlight=headers#setting-common-header-values  I however tried, and was unsuccessful. Ymmv.